# Invalid foreground RGBA argument

Tags: python

I try to run Pygame program,I get this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument
```

what should I do?

Here is the code:

```
newText = TextFont.render(text, True, (255, 255))
```

Comment: RGBA ... seems to need 4 numbers, not two. try (255,255,255,255)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you have to make the tuple with `(R,G,B)`. So for example:

```py
newText = TextFont.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255)) # Change the (R,G,B) to whatever value you want
```

Some code examples https://github.com/search?q=pygame.font.Font.render&type=Code&l=Python

For official documentation check https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#toc%20docutils

Comment: @funie200 It still needs a RGB please check the documentation